# What is the difference between "marked as duplicate" and "closed as duplicate"?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, closed-questions, duplicate-questions, on-hold

Sometimes questions are just "marked" <s>and sometimes they are "closed"</s> as duplicates.

Up until recently I thought it was "marked" when the question it's a duplicate of doesn't have an answer. But then I noticed [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/76533/41775) which is "marked" as a duplicate of a question which has a highly upvoted answer. (It's actually wrongly marked ATM, so future readers of this may find that it's no longer marked if they go to check.)

Or is "marked" the "duplicate equivalent" of "on-hold"?

Or does it happen when OP presses the "That solved my question" button?

Comment: Can you find an example of a question you see "closed as duplicate"? (and not "marked".)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Wow, good point. The mobile app says "closed" and the web-app says "marked".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Duplicate is special case of closing, because the question is still on topic on the site, just has been asked before. (Or after, on rare occasions.)

Since "closed" is associated with "off topic", I believe Stack Exchange team chose to make it more clear that duplicates are different, and are not closed in the same manner, hence the close banner on the question page itself says "marked as duplicate".

"closed as duplicate" appears in few other places:

- In the revisions page, as a technical matter - since only few people visit that page, I believe the team saw no real point spending time on making the code there dynamic.
- In the mobile apps, as the app doesn't make the check by itself - might be worth reporting and asking to change it, making the app more consistent with the site.